# Conditionally add IAsyncDisposable?

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild

.NET Standard 2.1 adds `IAsyncDisposable`. I can make use of that in an ORM API:

```
    public partial class MyDbContext : IAsyncDisposable
    {
        public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
        {
            if (Connection != null)
                await Connection.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
```

…but many of my users are still on .NET Standard 2.0. I know, I'll add preprocessor symbols!

```
#if NETSTANDARD2_1
    …
#endif
```

But, no. A .NET Core 3.0 app doesn't actually *set* `NETSTANDARD2_1`. So I can change it to `#if NETSTANDARD2_1 || NETCOREAPP3_0 || NETCOREAPP3_1`, but now my code will break once .NET 5 ships. And then again when .NET 6 ships a year later.

`NETCOREAPP` itself also probably doesn't work: .NET Core 2.2 and below don't support `IAsyncDisposable`.

TL;DR: how do I query "if .NET Standard 2.1 or .NET Core 3.0 *or newer*"?

**(edit)** This is generated source code, so I cannot access things like MSBuild. It needs to be a way that works from within C#.

**Update:** [It looks like](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/14540) the .NET 6.0 SDK will address this.

Comment: Do you distribute this API in source form or as compiled assembly?

Comment: Ah, good question. It's in source form — it's a code generator.

Comment: Maybe define your own preprocessor symbol and tell your users that they have to add it to their project settings if they want to have IAsyncDisposable support?

Comment: Yeah, that would be an option, but I was hoping for something more automatic. This stuff needs to work all the way back to .NET Framework 2.0 (yes, really… due to SQLCLR in SQL Server 2005), and I'd like to avoid having too many weird modes and switches.

Comment: But `IAsyncDisposable` supported in .NET Standard 2.0, there is a [Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces) package for that

Comment: No, it isn't. It's new to .NET Standard 2.1.

Comment: OK, yes, but I cannot rely on the package being there, so that's kind of moot. If people target .NET Standard 2.0 instead of 2.1, I have to assume they don't intend to use IAsyncDisposable.

Comment: Why can't you depend on a package like as @PavelAnikhouski suggests? That seems right and proper.

Comment: That would require changing something _outside_ of the generated C# code, and it also makes targeting .NET Standard at all kind of moot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is REALLY UGLY but you could put something like this at the top of code files where you need to check if `IAsyncDisposable` is supported:

```
#if (NETCOREAPP && !NETCOREAPP1_0 && !NETCOREAPP1_1 && !NETCOREAPP2_0 && !NETCOREAPP2_1 && !NETCOREAPP2_2) || (NETSTANDARD && !NETSTANDARD1_0 && !NETSTANDARD1_1 && !NETSTANDARD1_2 && !NETSTANDARD1_3 && !NETSTANDARD1_4 && !NETSTANDARD1_5 && !NETSTANDARD1_6 && !NETSTANDARD2_0)
    #define SUPPORTS_IASYNC_DISPOSABLE
#endif
```

Then later in the file you can just do

```
#if SUPPORTS_IASYNC_DISPOSABLE
    Console.WriteLine("Supported");
#else
    Console.WriteLine("Not supported");
#endif
```

This should work for future versions of .Net, assuming that they don't introduce a new version which for some reason *doesn't* support IAsyncDisposable.

Comment: :) hackish, yes, but that might in fact be the way to go!